# SELECT Roughly equals

Tags: oracle

I am transfering from access to oracle and couldn't find a roughly equals function in oracle. Does such a thing exist?

I am referring to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name ='*nswer is thi*';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE '%nswer is thi%';
```

**Explanation:**

This query will select records which contains "nswer is thi" anywhere in the field `name`.

For example:

```
name
--------------------
answer is this
blahnswer is thiblah
```

The LIKE conditions specify a test involving pattern matching. Whereas the equality operator (=) exactly matches one character value to another

Read more [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm).

Comment: If you are specifically searching for text, you might want to also look into the Soundex functions in Oracle SQL. This allows you to search for words that sound like the one you are looking for but might be spelt wrong.